# How to get to know if a Thread is running in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm making a thread the usual way and named it "Encoder". If the app closes and restarts again the object of the Thread is destroyed and recreated. Is there a way to get to know if the Thread that I started before is still running or not. ?

Comment: You can use the lifecycle events for your activity to know the app was closed and restarted.  And do the appropriate thing.

Comment: I just want to know if the Thread is still running or not. What Activity Lifecycle has to do with this ?

Comment: If your Activity is destroyed your Thread may still exist, but if your process is destroyed then all of its threads are gone.  Ultimately, the /proc/self/task pseudo-directory will allow you to enumerate the actual native threads involved in your activity, but it's not necessarily completely trivial to figure out the Java threads associated with those.  You may want to use a singleton to track the creation of your thread - which will of course end up null in any new process where the thread has not yet been created.

Comment: If the reference to this Thread is gone, usually there is no way to determine if it's still alive. But if you don't interrupt this Thread it will be alive till the work is done or the process is killed.

Answer (score 1):

You're designing your app wrong.

If the `Thread` will carry on the work after the activity died, and a new activity should be able to "pick up where the last one left", you should be using a `Service` to do this work and bind your activity to it.

You can read more about it and how to implement it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `.isAlive()`;

From doc:

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been
>   started and has not yet died.

Comment: I mentioned that the object of the Thread gets destroyed when I reopen the app. This won't work in that case.

Comment: Make the object a singleton.  If you are still in the original process then the singleton won't be destroyed as it is static with respect to a process.  If you are reopening in a new process, the singleton will be null, and you'll know that no thread is yet started.